Do string variables in records get freed when the record goes out of scope?
In Delphi you can declare a record containing a String. This means the record just contains a pointer the heap when the string is located; does the heap memory get freed when this record goes out of scope? Where would I find a documentation on such behavior?

I'm tempted to say "Try it by setting ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutDown to true". You might get the quickest answer.

Yes, strings are reference counted and the heap objects are freed when the reference count reaches zero, which happens when the last reference to the string goes out of scope. This includes references that are object and record members.

Where can I find information like this about how and when delphi frees stuff ? Are classes reference-counted ?

@JohnJohn: No, objects are created and freed explicitly (at least before we start working with interfaces). That's why idioms like var LFrog := LFrog.Create; try { use LFrog } finally LFrog.Free; end; are so important to follow strictly and always and carefully. I think you need a good Delphi textbook; although the documentation is fairly good in some parts, it is not so good in other parts. Also, it doesn't really cover everything you need to know about the language.

@AndreasRejbrand strings being reference-counted is just a (well-known) implementation detail. The string will get freed because it is a managed type, the compiler is responsible for allocating and freeing it.

@RemyLebeau: Not just "well known", but also documented.

@JohnJohn Interfaced objects are reference counted. And in early versions of the mobile compilers, non-interfaced objects were also reference counted, but not anymore since 10.4

Strings are managed types (which includes strings, dynamic arrays, interfaces, and variants). The compiler is responsible for allocating and freeing managed types in all contexts, including in records.
So yes, the compiler will emit code to free the string when the record goes out of scope.
